# Can't parse date

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using `Date.parse()` and I get NaN for this date string `01-Nov-2016`

Is there a way I can pass a patern to the parse function? if not, what's the best way to parse this date format?

Comment: Best way is to use an ISO8601 string. Alernatively, using the multi-argument constrictor to Date: `new Date(year, month[, date[, hours[, minutes[, seconds[, milliseconds]]]]]);`. If you're open to using non-core JS, then I suggest Moment.js. Core JS is not really good with date handling.

Comment: Just tried `new Date("01-Nov-2016")` in my console and it worked fine..

Comment: @DrewKennedy Interesting, it doesn't work on IE though

Comment: Got the same problem in Edge. Looks like different browsers have their own interpretation of the `Date` object. If I change your string to `Nov-01-2016`, it parses fine in Edge.

Comment: @DrewKennedy it doesn't work in Firefox, though. Again - JS date handling is _bad_ - use either ISO8601 or the full constructor if you don't want trouble. [Here are some examples of how dates are parsed weirdly](http://dygraphs.com/date-formats.html)

Comment: If you are not limited to use an external library you can use `momentjs`.  If you have the string `01-Nov-2016` and it's going to be always formatted like that you can use moment like this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/c2x2dwLs/